React (MUI) Page not loading on mobile
I have a react page using MUI components with the following main app code:
// Theme and other components
import React, { useEffect, useState, lazy, Suspense, MouseEvent } from 'react';
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material";
import ErrorBoundary from "./ErrorHandler/ErrorBoundary";
import Loader from "./Components/HelperComps/Loader";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

// Header / Footer
import ResponsiveAppBar from "./Components/HeaderFooter/ResponsiveAppBar";
import Footer from "./Components/HeaderFooter/Footer";
import WaterEffect from "./Components/HelperComps/WaterEffect/WaterEffect";
import {BANANA_CURSOR, MUSIC_MOUSE} from "./Stuff/ImagePaths";

// Pages (lazy loading)
const Home = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Home"));
const Live = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Live"));
const Studio = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Studio"));
const Aktuell = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Zeit/Aktuell"));
const Vergangenheit = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Zeit/Vergangenheit"));
const Zukunft = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Zeit/Zukunft"));
const Genesis = lazy(() => import("./Components/Pages/Zeit/Genesis"));
const Kontakt = lazy(() => import("./Components/HeaderFooter/FooterSites/Kontakt"));
const Datenschutz = lazy(() => import("./Components/HeaderFooter/FooterSites/Datenschutz"));
const Impressum = lazy(() => import("./Components/HeaderFooter/FooterSites/Impressum"));
const ErrorPage = lazy(() => import("./ErrorHandler/ErrorPage"));

// create a theme instance
const theme = createTheme({
    components: {
        MuiAppBar: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: {
                    height: '9vh',
                },
            },
        },
    },
});

interface MousePosition {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
    const [mousePos, setMousePos] = useState<MousePosition>({ x: 0, y: 0 });

    useEffect(() => {
        const minLoadingTime = 1000; // 1 second minimum loading time
        const startTime = Date.now();

        const handleLoad = () => {
            const elapsedTime = Date.now() - startTime;
            const remainingTime = minLoadingTime - elapsedTime;

            if (remainingTime > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setLoading(false);
                }, remainingTime);
            } else {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        // Adding event listener for when the entire page has loaded
        window.addEventListener('load', handleLoad);

        // Cleanup event listener on component unmount
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('load', handleLoad);
        };
    }, []);

    const handleMouseMove = (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        setMousePos({ x: event.clientX + window.scrollX, y: event.clientY + window.scrollY });
    };

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <ErrorBoundary>
                <Router>
                    <Box
                        // onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
                        sx={{
                            minHeight: '100 vh',
                            paddingBottom: '9vh',
                            paddingTop: '9vh',
                            position: 'relative',
                            overflow: 'hidden',
                            cursor: `url(${MUSIC_MOUSE}) 16 16, auto`,
                            /*'&::after': {
                                content: '""',
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                background: 'radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255, 255, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.8) 25%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2) 75%, rgba(255, 255, 0, 0) 100%)',
                                borderRadius: '50%',
                                position: 'absolute',
                                top: mousePos.y,
                                left: mousePos.x,
                                pointerEvents: 'none', // Ensure the effect doesn't interfere with pointer events
                                transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', // Center the effect exactly at the cursor
                            },*/
                        }}
                    >
                        {loading && <Loader />}
                        {!loading && (
                            <>
                                <ResponsiveAppBar />
                                <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                                    <Routes>
                                        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                                        <Route path="/zeit/genesis" element={<Genesis />} />
                                        <Route path="/zeit/vergangenheit" element={<Vergangenheit />} />
                                        <Route path="/zeit/aktuell" element={<Aktuell />} />
                                        <Route path="/zeit/zukunft" element={<Zukunft />} />
                                        <Route path="/studio" element={<Studio />} />
                                        <Route path="/live" element={<Live />} />
                                        <Route path="/kontakt" element={<Kontakt />} />
                                        <Route path="/datenschutz" element={<Datenschutz />} />
                                        <Route path="/impressum" element={<Impressum />} />
                                        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage errorCode="Error Code: 418" errorMessage="I'm a Teapot; #(RFC 2324, RFC 7168)" />} />
                                    </Routes>
                                </Suspense>
                                <Footer />
                            </>
                        )}
                    </Box>
                </Router>
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}

export default App;


My problem is, that the page is normally loaded on desktop butt on the mobile (smartphone tested) there is only the loader / Loading page showing up and no home.
I've tried with using a empty hello wolrd "home" page, to test. butt this did non function either.
Somebody a hint? Is there a real error in the code?
kind regards
shortly before, i tried to embed a own font in my page. i deleted this to test. and the stuff with the hello world page.

i made some small refactoring and delted all the lazy stuff, since i think i dont really need this. was a possibility that this would be the problem (google search). but my mobile page is not loading... if somebody knows how to solve this problem, this would be really nice.

hey there
i've solved the problem with adaptions in the useEffect stuff. i'm sorry. i don't know how to close the question... kind regards

if somenone is interested, i could send the new code.
